# API Error handling works in postman but client throws exception

Tags: php, node.js, express, error-handling

The error handling for my API sends beautiful, clear, and understanding messages if try using Postman. But while integrating with my client app (I use PHP) it always throws an exception.

Utility Error Response

```
class ErrorResponse extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
}

module.exports = ErrorResponse;
```

Error Middleware

```
const ErrorResponse = require('../Utils/errorResponse');

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    let error = {
        ...err
    };

    error.message = err.message;

    // Log to console for dev
    console.log(err);
    // console.log(err.response.data);

    // Mongoose bad ObjectId
    if (err.name === 'CastError') {
        const message = `Resource not found`;
        error = new ErrorResponse(message, 404);
    }

    // Mongoose duplicate key
    if (err.code === 11000) {
        const message = 'Duplicate field value entered';
        error = new ErrorResponse(message, 400);
    }

    // Mongoose validation error
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
        const message = Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message);
        error = new ErrorResponse(message, 400);
    }

    res.status(error.statusCode || 500).json({
        "status": "error",
        "message": error.message || 'Server Error'
    });
};

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

Example:

```
return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid credentials', 401));
```

I am using Guzzle, using the try-catch, but the response is not clean.

```
try {

} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
   return $e->getResponse();
}
```

Comment: You have no `throw` statement anywhere. What are you expecting to catch with `try/catch`? Returning an error is not the same as throwing it.

Comment: My problem is the Guzzle throws an error exception even I did not use try-catch, the below response as an example

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST http://localhost:3000/v2/transfers/name-enquiry` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"status":"error","message":"Invalid account, account not found"}

Comment: Resolved by adding the parameter: `'http_errors' => false` to Guzzle Client